# Update an array of objects to store daily data, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have documents in a collection that contain an array of objects. Each object in the array contains a date field. I want to update this array with a new object if the date is new, if it isn't I want to update the object with the same date in the array...

Here's an example schema:

```
const ExampleSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    members: [{ roleId: String, roleName: String, quantity: Number, color: String }],
    dailyLogs: [{ members: Number, verifiedMembers: Number, date: String }]
  },
);
```

I want to end up with an array that creates an object if the date doesn't exist, and if it exists I want to update the object with that date

```
name: 'name',
members: [...],
dailyLogs: [
{
  members: 4,
  verifiedMembers: 2,
  date: '02.13.2022'
}, 
{
  members: 8,
  verifiedMembers: 5,
  date: '02.14.2022'
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) for that,

```
db.collection.update({_id:"yourId"}, {$addToSet:{members: "yourMembers", verifiedMembers: "yourVerifiedMembers", dailyLogs:{date: "yourDate"}}});
```